# angular-2-dropdown-multiselect - Customize width 100%

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm implementing this **angular-2-dropdown-multiselect** component:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect

The component work properly but I need to set its with fit to the container...

I think that I just have to add "**width:100%**" somewhere but I don't know where I have to do it.

Another consideration:

The component is implemented in a Bootstrap application.

I have put the component inside a table like:

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <td>Search</td>
    <td><ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="myOptions" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" [(ngModel)]="optionsModel" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ss-multiselect-dropdown></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

## Consideration:

May be that considering switching from bootstrap table to a bootstrap form should render the listbox fit to container by default...

Thanks to support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" 
[settings]="dropdownSettings" 
></angular2-multiselect>
```

- **maxHeight:100**
  You can set the maxHeight of drop down in settings in your respective component ts file

  this.dropdownSettings = {
          singleSelection: false,
          text: "Select Users",
          selectAllText: 'Select All',
          unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
          enableSearchFilter: true,
          classes: "myclass custom-class",
          **maxHeight:150**
      };

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to set its width. Is it the button or the dropdown menu?

Anyway, you can set the width in the parent component's css file like this :

For the button :

```
ss-multiselect-dropdown > div.btn-group {
  width: 100%;
}
```

For the dropdown menu :

```
ss-multiselect-dropdown > div.btn-group > ul.dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
}
```

If it doesn't work, you may need to use deep styling like this :

```
:host >>> ss-multiselect-dropdown > div.btn-group {
 width: 100%;
}

:host >>> ss-multiselect-dropdown > div.btn-group > ul.dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
}
```

You should have a look at the [Component Styles](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html) page of Angular.io

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 'colspan'

```
<table class="table">
   <tr>
      <td>Search</td>
      <td colspan="#ofColumnsToSpan"><ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="myOptions" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" [(ngModel)]="optionsModel" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ss-multiselect-dropdown></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```